# What's the difference between FieldRef and ListProperty on SP 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2013

I'm programming on Sharepoint 2013 and I use the SPSiteDataQuery class to create a query that gets info from custom lists. I want to know the difference between.

```
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />";
```

AND

```
query.ViewFields = "<ListProperty Name='Title' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

ListProperty allows you to tell SPSiteDataQuery to return particular properties of the list like Title and ListId. FieldRef tells SPSiteDataQuery to return particular field values for specific list item.
Suppose you have list with two items and you set ViewFields property with one ListProperty tag for "ListId" of the list and one FieldRef tag for "Title" of the item. SPSiteDataQuery will return two items but they will have same value in "ListId" field because items are from the same list but they will have different values of "Title" field because they are different items.